# Disable dynamic mapping creation for only specific indexes on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to disable dynamic mapping creation for only specific indexes, not for all. For some reason I can't put *default* mapping with 'dynamic' : 'false'.
So, here left two options as I can see:

1. specify property *'index.mapper.dynamic'* in file *elasticsearch.yml*.
2. put *'index.mapper.dynamic'* at index creation time, as described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html#kibana-dynamic-mapping

First option may only accept values: true, false and strict. So there is no way to specify subset of specific indexes (like we do by pattern with property *'action.auto_create_index'* https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation).

Second option just not works. 
I've created index

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_idx/
{
    "settings" : {
        "mapper" : {
            "dynamic" : false
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "test_type" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then checked index settings:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/test_idx/_settings    
{
    "test_idx" : {
        "settings" : {
            "index" : {
                "mapper" : {
                    "dynamic" : "false"
                },
                "creation_date" : "1445440252221",
                "number_of_shards" : "1",
                "number_of_replicas" : "0",
                "version" : {
                    "created" : "1050299"
                },
                "uuid" : "5QSYSYoORNqCXtdYn51XfA"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and mapping:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/test_idx/_mapping
{
    "test_idx" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "test_type" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "field1" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so far so good, let's index document with undeclared field:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_idx/test_type/1
{
    "field1" : "it's ok, field must be in mapping and in source",
    "somefield" : "but this field must be in source only, not in mapping"
}
```

Then I've checked mapping again:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/test_idx/_mapping
{
    "test_idx" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "test_type" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "field1" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "somefield" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, mapping is extended regardless of index setting "dynamic" : false.
I've also tried to create index exactly as described in doc

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/test_idx
{
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false
}
```

but got the same behavior.

Maybe I've missed something?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sorry, forgot about version, I'm working with elastic 1.5.2.

Comment: See the last but one comment of answer, it's actually answer

Comment: `"settings.mapper.dynamic": false` disables automatic type creation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're almost there: the value needs to be set to `strict`.
And the correct usage is the following:

```
PUT /test_idx
{
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "dynamic":"strict",
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And pushing this a bit further, if you want to forbid the creation even of new types, not only fields in that index, use this:

```
PUT /test_idx
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": "strict"
    },
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Without `_default_` template:

```
PUT /test_idx
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately I have to disable dynamic mapping creation for whole index (index-level). At your example it was disabled just for type 'test_type'. And I can't use '_default_' mapping for this (as I told in the beginning)

Comment: The `_default_` mapping needs to be used in order to disable index-level creation of fields/types.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put `_default_` mapping. I'm trying to understand how to disable dynamic mapping creation without put any mappings at all (disable dynamic mapping by putting other mapping is a bit tricky from API point of view, IMHO)

Comment: Yeah, there is a way. See my last attempt using `settings` and, also, `"dynamic": "strict"` for the mapping of a single type.

Comment: Just curious: does my last suggestion work for you? Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Andrei. All snippets of code, you've provided works fine, but unfortunately not solves my problem because all of them requires put mapping. I want to disable dynamic mapping on index(es) level without put any mapping to index itself. And I just not understand why elastic property that seems should solve exactly my problem (`index.mapper.dynamic`) not works.

Comment: First of all it's weird to disable mapping by put other mapping. Our legacy technical solution just can't put mapping to index at index creation time atomically. So put mapping happens incrementally after index creation, it's separated procedure. We have multiple elastic clients and f.ex. when first client just created index and prepares to create correct mapping, second client pushes document and elastic creates dynamic (unwanted) mapping. I want to avoid such behavior by disable dynamic mapping at index creation request or by elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: First of all, `index.mapper.dynamic` is not a dynamic setting. You cannot change this setting **after the index** has been created. If you want that setting to an index, it should be specified at index creation time. **There's no other way, this is how Elasticsearch works**. Secondly, it doesn't make any sense to change that setting after index has been created already. It's like bypassing the `strict` nature of the configuration that you want protected.

Comment: Do this: close the index `POST /test_idx/_close`. Run `PUT /test_idx/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "mapper.dynamic": false
  }
}`. Open the index `POST /test_idx/_open`. Now it shouldn't allow any new types to be added to the index.

Comment: There is no place where I told that I want use `index.mapper.dynamic` **after** index creation. If you refer to my question (last code snippet), I'm specifying this setting exactly in index creation request. And it works in weird way: it disallows **creation** of new mapping by just putting documents (solves my case), but in same time allows to dynamically map new fields after manual mapping creation. So dynamic is still on. Seems it's a bug, if not and it's expected behavior - property is incorrectly named, it should be smth like `index.mapping.autocreate` instead of `index.mapping.dynamic`.

Comment: I tested those commands and I can't create a field, nor a new type, nothing new can be added to that mapping after using what I wrote in my response. And you say contradictory things. I give up. I still don't understand what you are trying to say, I'm sorry. Good luck finding a solution to your issue (whatever that issue is).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andrei. Sorry for that. Maybe we are using different versions.

Comment: It's not about the version. It's about the problem description itself. It doesn't make sense. You said **So put mapping happens incrementally after index creation, it's separated procedure.** this means you run a PUT mapping after the index is already created. Then you say **There is no place where I told that I want use index.mapper.dynamic after index creation.**. You also said **I want to disable dynamic mapping on index(es) level without put any mapping to index itself** and I suggested `PUT /test_idx/_settings {"index":{ "mapper.dynamic": false}}` that changes `_settings`, not `_mapping`.

Comment: What's wrong with description? I told that I put mapping after creation of index. Also I told that at index creation time I put setting `index.mapper.dynamic`, as described in elastc doc. Thanks for your suggestion: `PUT /test_idx/_settings {"index":{ "mapper.dynamic": false}}`, but I want to make this request and index creation request as one (atomically, by single request). In my case this not works. I'm trying to understand does elastic docs has tricky/non-working example or I missed something. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html#kibana-dynamic-mapping.

Comment: If you do exactly this and the **index is not yet created** `PUT test
{
  "index.mapper.dynamic": false
}`, the index will be created but you will not be able to add anything to it. If you try to do this: `POST /test/test_type/1
{
  "field1": "whatever"
}` you will get back `TypeMissingException[[test] type[[test_type, trying to auto create mapping, but dynamic mapping is disabled]] missing]`.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, this is solves my current problem. But behavior is like "mapper.autocreate:false", not "mapping.dynamic:false" I mean if you now (after receiving `TypeMissingException`) put some mapping `PUT /test_index/_mapping/test_type {"test_type" : {"properties":{"field1" : {"type" : "string"}}}}` this mapping will be created as dynamic (i.e. it will start accept unmapped fields), ignoring my index-level setting `"index.mapper.dynamic": false` I'm expecting inheritance of `mapping.dynamic:false` for any mapping in index, until I explicitly specify other.

Comment: And your expectation is not to be able to create a `_mapping` manually and automatically?

Comment: No, I expect user is able to create `_mapping` via `_mapping` API, but this mapping must inherit settings from index (if not overriden in `_default_` mapping or in mapping that under is going to create). In my case index created with `"index.mapper.dynamic": false`, no any mappings exists and I'm not specifying explicitly `dynamic` property in mapping, that I'm going to create. I'm expecting new mapping with `dynamic:false` behavior, because I specified for index itself.

Comment: No, there are two separate settings. The index level one and the mapping level one. This is from documentation: **The dynamic creation of mappings for unmapped types can be completely disabled by setting index.mapper.dynamic to false.

The dynamic creation of fields within a type can be completely disabled by setting the dynamic property of the type to strict.** The index level setting is for creating new mappings (for new types). The type level one is for fields within that specific type. `index.mapper.dynamic` is not inherited to new types, because the type level setting is a different one.

Comment: Thank you, really thanks a lot! You've answered on my question. I'll ask elasticsearch team about renaming this confusing name for property `index.mapper.dynamic` to something like `index.mapper.autocreate_mapping`.

Comment: Btw, that snippet from the documentation is from [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html#mapping-dynamic-mapping).

Comment: I've read this doc many times, confusing that both `index.mapper.dynamic` and `dynamic` property inside mapping can take `strict` value. And much more confusing is incorrect picked up name of the property `index.mapper.dynamic`. It's doesn't control dynamic actually, it controls auto creation of mapping. F.ex. elastic has property `action.auto_create_index` -  it's clear, this property controls index auto creation. But anyway it's a question to developer that picked up this name. Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

You must know about that the below part just mean that ES could'nt create a type dynamically.

```
"mapper" : {
        "dynamic" : false
    }
```

You should configure ES like this:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/test_idx/_mapping/test_type
{
  "dynamic":"strict"
}
```

Then you cant't index other field that without mapping any more ,and get an error as follow:

```
mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [hatae] within [data] is not allowed
```

If you wanna store the data,but make the field can't be index,you could take the setting like this:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/test_idx/_mapping/test_type
{
  "dynamic":false
}
```

Hope these can help the people with the same issue :).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the doc (7x.): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/dynamic.html

> The dynamic setting controls whether new fields can be added
>   dynamically or not. It accepts three settings:
>
> **true**
>
> Newly detected fields are added to the mapping. (default)
>
> **false**
>
> Newly detected fields are ignored. These fields will not be indexed so
>   will not be searchable but will still appear in the _source field of
>   returned hits. These fields will not be added to the mapping, new
>   fields must be added explicitly.
>
> **strict**
>
> If new fields are detected, an exception is thrown and the document is
>   rejected. New fields must be explicitly added to the mapping.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict", 
    "properties": {
      "user": { 
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "social_networks": { 
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so this is only possible when creating index?

Comment: Well, as far as I remember you can do this as an update to: not only during creation, but afterwards too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable dynamic mapping in ES 7 anymore, what you can do if you have completely unstructured data is to disable completely the mapping for the index like this:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "enabled": false 
  }
}
'
```

if you are using python you can do this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# Connect to the elastic cluster
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])

request_body = {
        "mappings": {
                 "enabled": False
    }
}
es.indices.create(index = 'my_index', body = request_body)
```

Comment: I don't know which version you are using but it seems it works just fine in 7.x (at least 7.6.0).

Comment: I am using 7.4 version, I had to disable completely the mapping because each object has a different structure

Comment: I downvoted this as the answer is not accurate and can be misleading to others. As the answer by avetisk notes, this is still possible in 7.x (I've tested 7.7.0) and the documentation still shows it as supported. The only thing that changed is the removal of the type, so the options go directly under "mappings" now.

Answer (score 0):

For ES 7 if you want to update an existing index:

```
PUT customers/_mapping
{
  "dynamic": "strict"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, please be concern aboout value **false** or **strict**,they work in a different way.

using "dynamic": "false" and create documents with fields not covered by the mapping, those fields will be ignored (so they won't be stored) and wouldn't show up in _source when you GET the document.

where value **strict** will not allow you to create the document rather it will throw an exception

Inner objects inherit the dynamic setting from their parent object or from the mapping type. In the following example, dynamic mapping is disabled at the type level, so no new top-level fields will be added dynamically.

However, the user.social_networks object enables dynamic mapping, so you can add fields to this inner object.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false, 
    "properties": {
      "user": { 
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "social_networks": {
            "dynamic": true, 
            "properties": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you are using **node.js** client

```
    await this.client.indices.putMapping({
      index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
      body: {
        dynamic: 'strict',
        properties: {
          ...this.schema,
        },
      },
    });
```