# Elasticsearch 5.x.x cannot disable dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to simply disable dynamic mapping for any fields not explicitly defined in the mapping at index creation time. Nothing would work, so I even tried the example in their docs

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Made a test insert:

```
POST my_index/my_type
{
  "user": "tester",
  "some_unknown_field": "lsdkfjsd"
}
```

Then searching the index shows:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "AViPrfwVko8c8Q3co8Qz",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "user": "tester",
          "some_unknown_field": "lsdkfjsd"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm expecting "some_unknown_field" to not be indexed, since it was not defined in the mapping. So why is it still being indexed? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that it isn't currently possible in version 5.0.0 to do what I wanted, so I removed the fields in my app before sending to elasticsearch and achieved the same end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What mapping does is to have your field as the type which you mention, when you create the index using the `mapping`. So for a field which you haven't mentioned anything during the mapping and then trying to insert values, ES will always consider it as a new field and will add it to the index with a `default mapping`. So if you don't want to see a particular field within your `_source` you could do some [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html).

**Work arounds**:

1. If that's not the case try disabling the [default mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/default-mapping.html) when
   you're creating the index.
2. Try making the property `dynamic` into `strict`:

   ```
   PUT /test
       {
         "settings": {
           "index.mapper.dynamic": false
         },
         "mappings": {
           "testing_type": {
             "dynamic":"strict",
             "properties": {
               "field1": {
                 "type": "string"
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
   ```

If the above two doesn't work out, try making `index_mapper_dynamic`to false. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263673/disable-dynamic-mapping-creation-for-only-specific-indexes-on-elasticsearch) could be handy. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yea the source filtering does work, but that's not really what I'm trying to do. I don't want the extra fields to even enter the index at all, I want them completely ignored. And strict also won't work because it rejects the whole document, not just the extra fields. I don't think this it is possible to do what I'm wanting with the current version, I think i'll have to remove the fields in my app layer before sending to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @deRaad yup seems like that's the only option. How about making the `index_mapper_dynamic:false` before doing the mapping. "settings": {
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false. I've updated the answer.
  },

Comment: im assuming `strict` and `false` are the same if im cloud-hosted and can't view server logs at the moment :)