# Why are these fields falling through to elasticsearch that are not defined in my index template?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I disabled dynamic fields in my index template:

```
{
  "template": "logstash-mysexylogs*",
  "order": 10,
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
```

Now as I am looking over my logs in Kibana I will occasionally see this:
[image]

These fields where not defined in the template so they shouldn't exist AT ALL, but for a few logs I will see them as shown in that screen shot.

Why does this happen and only happen with a few (not all logs) and how do I prevent this from happening?

These particular fields would be present in ALL the logs if I was not filtering them out in the template so Im confused why this is happening with only a scant few and not all of them.

Comment: As elasticsearch is schemeless, it will try to index the entire document as provided to it. The yellow mark indicates that the field (in your case userAgent_patch, userAgent_minor, etc.) has no proper mapping(kept as noot_analyzed). so you could do two things:
1. In order to remove this sign, update the mapping for the index pattern.
2. Look why are these fields being provided to elasticsearch (remove them before sending it to elasticseach). You can use mutate logstash plugin, to add or remove a field.

Comment: Look at the mapping of the index using a rest command to Elasticsearch, not from Kibana. And if you can provide the full mapping in a gist here.

Comment: You need to set dynamic to strict.
   `"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": "strict"
    }
  }
` [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263673/disable-dynamic-mapping-creation-for-only-specific-indexes-on-elasticsearch) may be helpful

Comment: You could post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set dynamic to strict.

```
"mappings": { 
  "_default_": { 
    "dynamic": "strict" 
  } 
}
```

Per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html),
if elasticsearch detects a new field, it will by default add it to the mapping. Setting `"dynamic": false` turns this setting off, and new fields won't dynamically be added.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263673/disable-dynamic-mapping-creation-for-only-specific-indexes-on-elasticsearch) post may also be helpful.

Comment: Does logstash behave differently? I use logstash to apply templates to indices. When I set this logstash just started dropping all docs that had fields not defined in the template. I dont want that I just want it to not add those fields.

Comment: If your template is set to strict and you have fields being passed through that are not defined in the template, elasticsearch will throw a 400 error and will fail to create the document. You can see the error in the logstash logs. You'll either want to select your input data differently, i.e. explicitly, or you can use the mutate filter to remove the fields. `filter { mutate { remove_field => ['unwanted_field', 'unwanted_tag'] }}`

Comment: Ah ok that was what I wasn't sure about. I wanted to avoid explicitly doing mutant or something if it could be avoided be i guess it cannot. Why does it have to reject the entire document instead of just not add those fields?

Comment: Elasticsearch might assume that if the mapping is strict, then you know what the data looks like, and you dont want any bad data being passed in.  From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html): "`strict` If new fields are detected, an exception is thrown and the document is rejected"